# mysql json_extract dynamic position

Tags: mysql, sql, json, string-concatenation

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(column,'$.parent[3].child') AS child FROM table 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(column,'$.parent[3].child') IN (1)
```

this is my sql query. i have a also column `jsonlength` how can i connect this 2 columns in one query ? i want to change `3` to dynamic number given in `jsonlength`

for example:

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(column,'$.parent['jsonlength'].child') AS child FROM table 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(column,'$.parent['jsonlength'].child') IN (1)
```

but this query not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to form the JSON path with string concatenation. In MySQL, this is done with the [CONCAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
SELECT id, JSON_EXTRACT(column, CONCAT('$.parent[',jsonlength,'].child')) AS child FROM table 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(column,CONCAT('$.parent[',jsonlength,'].child')) IN (1)
```